# A way to enforce uniqueness across multiple rows, or redesign such that it is not necessary?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to model "serial numbers assigned to things". I want to treat serial numbers as composed of smaller units of runs of digits or characters -- so a serial number like "AB12CD" would be stored as the triple `("AB", 12, "CD") :: (varchar, int, varchar)`. The serial numbers may have any number of components (though likely values are just between 2 and 6), and the components will always match `(\d+)|([a-z]+)`. The intent here is to aid queries such as "all things where component N is between i and j", without having to resort to string manipulations on each row (split on some separator, parse ints, keep track of ordinals).

The issue I have is that I would like to enforce serial number uniqueness in the database, but with my current idea I don't see a way to get there. The table is something like:

```
thing_id | component | char_part | num_part
------------------------------------------
1        | 1         | "AB"      | null
1        | 2         | null      | 12
2        | 1         | "AB"      | null
2        | 2         | null      | 12
```

So in the above table, thing 1 and thing 2 are both conceptually assigned serial number "AB12". An indexed view with a unique constraint would solve this, but I'd have to use a CTE to recursively join the ordinals-per-thing, and CTEs in indexed views are not possible. If I could do a CTE in an indexed view, I'd be able to index the following, and apply a unique constraint on "SN", which would get violated and life would be good:

```
thing_id | SN
------------------
1        | "AB12"
2        | "AB12"
```

Is there a pattern that might be recommended for this, or a way to enforce "multi-row uniqueness"? I am hoping to not have to keep two tables manually in sync (one with combined string values, one with chopped up components).

### Update / answer-ish

I removed the `char_part` and `num_part` columns, and moved their contents into XML nodes in an XML column, and then created a persisted computed column that is built from the XML elements. Now there is only one row per serial number -- the XML column contains the arbitrary number of components, and the computed column has a uniqueness constraint applied to it.

This isn't perfect - it requires clients to submit XML, and querying XML appears to be a little slower than I'd hoped for, but it appears to be a working approach to this problem.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. What is "ordinal" ? Can you supply some code and then explain why it doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Is a serial number always built from 3 components, or can one be built on an arbitrary number of components?'

Comment: Any number, but will generally probably be between 2 and 6 components

Answer (score 0):

I started in on this, talked myself into loops, and ended up with more questions than answers. Sorry about that. Posting anyone, as “outside discussion” might help get you to the proper solution for your problem.

Based on what you’ve said, I see this is a normalization problem. Tackled that way, I come up with the following, which may not quite be what your are looking for. Making names up as I go along…

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Component
 (
    Component   varchar(10)  not null  primary key
 )
```

Sample data in table Component:

```
AB
CD
12
34
```

(I’m not sure how this correlates to your `char_part` and `num_part` values; I’m working from the assumption that each component has a unique identifier. If you have different indentifying codes for different types of components, then you have a much more complex problem.)

Next, table Thing, which while built/assembled from Components, is still its own, uh, thing, and so requires its own properly normalized one-thing-per-row table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Thing
 (
   ThingId  int  not null  identity(1,1)  primary key
 )
```

Sample data:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Next up, what links Things with Components? A many-to-many table!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ThingComposition
 (
    ThingId     int          not null
   ,Component   varchar(10)  not null
   ,primary key clustered (ThingId, Component)
 )
```

With data

```
1, AB
1, 12
2, AB
2, 23
3, AB
4, CD
4, 12
4, 34
```

This structure, or something similar, should support your searching by slice-and-dice requirements

The above data would produce serial numbers like:

```
1   AB12
2   AB23
3   AB
4   CD1234
```

However, I can’t think of anything reasonable* and declarative within SQL that keeps you from having the following in table ThingComposition:

```
1, AB
1, 12
5, AB
5, 12
```

Much also depends on how you construct your serial numbers from the base component codes, which is not clear from your description. Are both “AB12” and “12AB” valid serial numbers? Further problems crop up—how do you enforce serial number uniqueness as rows are added, updated, and deleted across multiple tables over time? If you have an “AB12”, how do you add “AB1234”, if you have to add elements one row at a time? Do you “build” a Thing and then flip a bit (IsLive) saying “done, now enforce uniqueness”? (Can be done—filtered unique indexes.) Do serial numbers (components in a thing) change over time? The mind boggles.

I was going to suggest

```
CREATE TABLE Thing
 (
   ThingId       int           not null  identity(1,1)  primary key
  ,SerialNumber  varchar(100)  not null  --  enough characters?
 )
```

with a unique index on SerialNumber and carefully constructed application code to construct and populate it with the correct SerialNumber, but yeah, this gets complex fast. I’ve ended up with lots of open questions, and am not able to answer them. Hopefully someone else comes up with a better idea!

* Triggers are not reasonable. Do not use triggers.

Comment: "If you have an “AB12”, how do you add “AB1234”, if you have to add elements one row at a time?" This would decompose into ("AB",12) and ("AB", 1234), which are unique pairs. But I think I see your point: Wouldn't there be a conflict during insertion between the first elements (or the first N elements for anything that only differs in the N+1 element)? I guess the answer is yes -- which makes me feel I can't enforce this in the DB.